# How to build Chainlink request so that the response will be sent to another contract?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am currently exploring the Chainlink API Consumer smart contract that brings off-chain data to the smart contract through GET request.

There is an understandable [example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/#api-consumer-example) of how to perform such task. I am curious, how to initialize the third argument in `buildChainlinkRequest` function during the contract construction so that instead of `this.fulfill.selector` will be placed another argument?

**From this**:

```
Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
```

**To customizable third argument**:

```
Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, callback, callbackFunctionSignature);
```

---

For illustration something like this idea:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    // For example: 0xContractAddr.contractFunction.selector;
    bytes4 callbackFunctionSignature; // <-- added
    address callback; // <-- added
    
    constructor(bytes4 _callbackFunctionSignature) {  // <-- added
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
        jobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)

        callbackFunctionSignature = _callbackFunctionSignature; // <-- added
    }
    
    function changeCallbackFunctionSignature(bytes4 _callbackFunctionSignature) public {
        callbackFunctionSignature = _callbackFunctionSignature;
    } // <-- added

    function changeCallback(address _callback) public {
        callback = _callback;
    } // <-- added

    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, callback, callbackFunctionSignature); // <-- added
        

        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        
        request.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        

        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }

}
```

I've tried to use `abi.encodeWithSelector()` but it modifies only function + arguments without specifying a contract address unless you call.

TL;DR. How to make the `callbackFunctionSignature` parameter in `buildChainlinkRequest` function dinamic?

Answer (score 1):

**For now, this is not currently supported in the docs**, so it is not recommended to go with this approach as it breaks the recording of requestId's and you must remove the modifier which prevents addresses other than the Oracle to call the `fulfill()` function.  If you really want to test this technique, you can, however, you'll need to manually modify some code (**at your own security risk**):

The default behavior in the [ChainlinkClient.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol) (line 104) import is to automatically put the receiving contract as the same contract that sent the request. You must change line 104 of the import to state this instead:
`req.callbackAddress`. You also have to remove the `recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)` modifier on the `fulfill()` method. You're going to want at least to put your own require statement here to be sure the only entity that can run the `fulfill()` method is the oracle you sent the request to.

Doing this will work, but again as this is currently not supported in the docs, **you must take extra precautions in ensuring this is done securely**.